# Apache forward proxy, only allow proxy to specific hosts, deny everything else

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I've set up a forward proxy using Apache 2.4.  I want to allow proxy users access to seven different domains and deny everything else.  I've configured the access to the seven domain as follows:

```
# Allow proxy only to these test sites
<ProxyMatch ^https\:.{1,20}\.?test\.(com|io|zone)>
      Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/password-protect.conf
</ProxyMatch>

<ProxyMatch ^https\:.{1,20}\.?testhost\.(cloud|com|io)>
      Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/password-protect.conf
</ProxyMatch>

<ProxyMatch ^https\:.{1,20}\.?test-content\.com>
      Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/password-protect.conf
</ProxyMatch>
```

I've temporarily included password protection in each of the ProxyMatch directives so I can verify the regex is being matched.  That part works properly.  The problem I have is I cannot figure out a way to deny everything else.  I've added a ProxyMatch tag to deny * and it does deny everything.  Apache doesn't just find the first matching ProxyMatch and then stop.  The last deny all matches everything.

I think I can create a complex regex where I take the three ProxyMatch regex expressions, add a NOT operator to each and "or" them all together.  That seems like a huge mess.  If I add more regex matches later, my "catch all" ProxyMatch will be unmaintainable.  Just want to check to see if there is a better way to create a catch-all deny for any proxy requests that do not match the three ProxyMatch expressions above.  I've already looked at all the proxy directives in the mod_proxy documentation.  Don't see any way to do this without being messy.

Comment: did you put your "ProxyMatch deny" as last in config ? because: `The first rule that matches wins.`

Comment: you can also use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if instead `ProxyMatch` and deny inside `Else`

Comment: Yes, I put the deny last.  It appears that every match wins.